"Friction at a contact point", rubber-band experiment
I was working on some practice problems in my book, and the question was to describe all the energy conversions that happens when a person pulls on a rubber band and hits it on a board (any type of board). I was grinding through the series of conversions, until I began to wonder about one thing:
When the rubber band hits the board, its kinetic energy is transformed into sound (I experimented); But is there heat that produces also, when the rubber band hits the board? My question is if there is any friction at a contact point. If we assume there is no force vertically but only horizontally, then will there be heat (caused by friction) that will form when the rubber band hits the board?

Yes, there will be some heat produced as a result of friction between the rubber band and the board, and also some heat produced as a result of internal friction within the rubber band itself, as it is deformed.

Thank you @gandalf61!
